# NullPointerException using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am having a problem with my code here. I am using SharedPreferences in my code, and I am getting a NullPointerException at one line in the code. Here's the full code:

```
    public class Exercise extends Activity {
String WEIGHT = "0";
String AGE = "0";
String FEET = "0";
String INCHES = "0";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.exercise);

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putInt(WEIGHT, 0);
    prefsEditor.putInt(AGE, 0);
    prefsEditor.putInt(FEET, 0);
    prefsEditor.putInt(INCHES, 0);
    prefsEditor.commit();


    final EditText weightField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextWeight);
    try {
        prefsEditor.putInt(WEIGHT, Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText().toString()));
        prefsEditor.commit();
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
    }
```

The NullPointerException appears at this line:

```
prefsEditor.putInt(WEIGHT, Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText().toString()));
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the activity that calls setContentView(R.layout.main):

```
public class CalorieIntakeCalculator extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

public void next(View view) {
    Intent intentExercise = new Intent(view.getContext(), Exercise.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentExercise, 0);
} 
}
```

When the "next" button is pushed in main.xml, it sends `next` which switches Activities from CalorieIntakeCalculator to Exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you successfully used prefsEditor several times above that line, it seems like weightField must be null. Have you checked its value in the debugger?

EDIT: I also just noticed that you never assigned a value to WEIGHT, nor any of the other Strings for the SharedPreferences keys, so they are all null. You need to fix that.

```
String WEIGHT = "weight";
String AGE = "age";
String FEET = "feet";
String INCHES = "inches";
```

For the weight field, make sure there is an EditText in your exercise layout that has the id R.id.EditTextWeight

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! Yes, weightField was null when I checked the debugger. I am still a learning beginner, though, and do not know how to fix either of the problems. Help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you so much again! 
I fixed the first problem of assigning the values to the Strings.
But I couldn't fix the other problem because the EditText with id R.id.EditTextWeight is in main.xml. I have posted the other activity which calls setContentView(R.layout.main)

Comment: In the Exercise class, you call setContentView(R.layout.exercise). Then, when you set weightField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextWeight); it is looking in the exercise.xml layout file (NOT the main.xml layout file) for an EditText with the id EditTextWeight. If it is not in that layout file, it is going to return null.